# how can i access IBOutlet in another class? in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I'm sorry i have bad eng skill.

i want access IBOutlet in another class.
i found many question in stackoverflow, but all answer not working in my code

firstly this is my code.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var MainViewController: UIView! = nil
@IBOutlet var LyricsViewController: UIView! = nil
@IBOutlet var ListViewController: UIView! = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   showMainViewController()    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func showMainViewController(){
    MainViewController.alpha = 1
    LyricsViewController.alpha = 0
    ListViewController.alpha = 0
}
func showLyricsViewController(){
    MainViewController.alpha = 0
    LyricsViewController.alpha = 1
    ListViewController.alpha = 0
}
func showListViewController(){
    MainViewController.alpha = 0
    LyricsViewController.alpha = 0
    ListViewController.alpha = 1
}

}
```

and i want access ViewController's function in this class

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController : UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!
var listBoolean = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func LinkListView(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(listBoolean == false){
        ViewController().showListViewController()
        listBoolean = true
    }
    else{
        ViewController().showMainViewController()
        listBoolean = false

    }

}

}
```

func showMainViewController() is work in ViewController's viewDidLoad()
but error in SecondViewController with this setance

> fatal error : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Just a tip unrelated to the question : don't call a variable `...viewController` if  it's an `UIView` object, and always start a variable or method name with a lowercase in order to avoid confusion with classes name.

Answer (score 7):

You have to create a object of view controller and then access it.
Ex:-

```
var dash : abcViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("abc") as! abcViewController
var a = dash.getXYZ()
```

Like this way you access the variable and function of other view controller.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the ViewController is not yet loaded. You create a variable to store it temporarily. When the ViewController appears, under your `viewDidLoad` method, assign the variable to the IBOutlet.

Example:

In the `FirstViewController` you want to pass a string message say "pass message" to `SecondViewController` and display on a label of IBOutlet. You can't assign the string directly to `SecondViewController` on `FirstViewController`. You have to create a string first.

When your `SecondViewController` loads, in the `viewDidLoad` method, assign the "pass message" string to the label to display. That is how you display on your IBOutlet.

Just in case:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController{
 // All your above codes.

func PassMessage(){
     let displayViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
     displayViewController.message = "pass message"
    }
}
```

In SecondViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
var message = ""

override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.displayLabel.text = message
    }
}
```

Note: Assign `SecondViewController` in the StoryboardID.

Comment: i'm very sorry i can't understand your answer because i have lower dev skill. can i get the example code??

Comment: I've edited my answer. You should understand by now.

Comment: i'm sorry i still have error. but i'm very thank you for your answer

Comment: create another boolean variable in your SecondViewController, inside the if-else statement set the boolean value of SecondViewController. When your SecondViewController loads, inside viewDidLoad method, check boolean value, and run the respective methods in it.

Comment: I can only help you this far. You have to learn and think it thru yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this function for previous class function operations

```
let appdel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let nav : UINavigationController! = window.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

for(var i:Int = 0 ; i < nav.viewControllers.count ; i++)
    {
        let viewc :  UIViewController = nav.viewControllers[i]
        if(viewc.respondsToSelector("showListViewController"))
        {
            viewc.performSelector("showListViewController")
        }
    }
```