# How can I access IBOutlet in another class?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, iboutlet

I am having the same error that is in this question: [how can i access IBOutlet in another class? in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358225/how-can-i-access-iboutlet-in-another-class-in-swift) but when I write in my Xcode (for iOS 8 with Swift 3) I have an error.

My code is this. I want to edit `amauntOut` (is an `UILabel`) that is in the class `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` with the action of one button:

```
@IBAction func actionTextb(_ sender: Any) {
    print("you writted \(String(describing: amauntEnter.text!))----")

    //Convert_Table_Third_Cell.amauntOut.text = amauntEnter.text ----> is a tried
    //var dash : abcViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("abc") as! abcViewController ----> is a tried
    //var a = dash.getXYZ() ----> is a tried

    var update: Convert_Table_Third_Cell = UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(UIStoryboard) as! Convert_Table_Third_Cell
    update.amauntOut.text = "hola"
}
```

I get this error:

> Instance member 'instantiateViewController' cannot be used on type 'UIStoryboard'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Can someone help me?

this is the first class

```html
import UIKit

class Convert_Table_Second_Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var amauntEnter: UITextField!

    var theNumber = getTheNumber()



    @IBAction func actionTextb(_ sender: Any) {
        print("you writted \(String(describing: amauntEnter.text!))----")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "convert ID", bundle: nil)
        let update = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "convert ID") as!  Convert_Table_Third_Cell

        update.amauntOut.text = "hola"


        let aa = "hola hillel----------------------"
        print(aa)
        print(theNumber.usedParameters(ArrayOfNumbers: unitInOutlet, TipOfData: 3))

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print("this is the valeu \(theNumber.hola)")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

this is the second where is the label that I want to edit

import UIKit

class Convert_Table_Third_Cell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var amauntOut: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var UnityMeasurment: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. A view controller is initiated when it is displayed on the screen. One and only on view controller object can be displayed at one time. In your code, you are initiating a brand new view controller and set text to outlets. So that won't work. Instead, you need to set text to the text field on the existing instance of you view controller.

To do so, in the view controller that you want to receive text field content updates, register in notification center to receive a content update function calls.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(listnerFunction(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil)

func listnerFunction(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? String {
        self.textField.text = data
    }
}
```

Then in another view controller, if you want to send text to the above view controller and update text, simply post the data to notification center

```
let data:[String: String] = ["data": "YourData"]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Instance member 'instantiateViewController' cannot be used on type 'UIStoryboard'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

It say that you cannot use `instance member` of `instantiateViewController` by a `class` of `UIStoryboard`.

Change `var update: Convert_Table_Third_Cell = UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(UIStoryboard) as! Convert_Table_Third_Cell`
 to `var update: Convert_Table_Third_Cell = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: {YourStoryBoardID}) as! Convert_Table_Third_Cell`

Comment: thanks but I have a problem when I write `var update: Convert_Table_Third_Cell = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "convert ID") as! Convert_Table_Third_Cell` I got an error that 'Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard'' and when I change with UIStorybord 'Instance member 'instantiateViewController' cannot be used on type 'UIStoryboard'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?' like a comment is a UITableViewCell

Comment: `storyboard` is member of `UIViewController`. You can use `UIStoryboard.init(name: "{Your Storyboard Name}", bundle: nil)` insteaded.

Comment: it send me this error: `Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'Convert_Table_Third_Cell' always fails` I didn't now how repair it.

Comment: it seems you call `actionTextb(_ sender: Any)` in class which you never mentioned and you update `amauntOut` in `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` which you didn't know what exactly `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` is. post more code to let us help you. 1. where is `actionTextb(_ sender: Any)`? 2. when will it triggered? 3. which `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` you want to update?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I mention `@IBOutlet var amauntOut: UILabel!` in `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` I will post the 2 clases in the question

Comment: It looks a bit strange that you initiate `Convert_Table_Third_Cell` in `Convert_Table_Second_Cell` without add cell to tableview!! And if you want to access member of `Convert_Table_Second_Cell` in `Convert_Table_Third_Cell`, there is serveral solution. 1. Use protocol
(delegate).  2. Pass instance of `Convert_Table_Second_Cell` to `Convert_Table_Third_Cell`. 3. Use Notification.